# Class CaptureDelegate is implemented in python and mediapipe. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined

Tags: python, macos, opencv, mediapipe

I am setuping up a simple project using jupyter notebooks and mediapipe in vscode.
All I am doing is displaying my webcam feed. The issue arises when I try and close the window(by pressing q). The application freezes and I have to force quit it. From what I understand the error message basically just says that I have two versions of opencv that are conflicting(not sure if my understanding is correct). How should I go about fixing this? Thanks.

This is how I installed and setup mediapipe and opencv:

```
!pip3 install mediapipe-silicon opencv-python
```

This is my code:

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp 
import numpy as np 
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_pose = mp.solutions.pose 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("Mediapip Feed", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The error I am getting is:

```
13:04:39.791 [error] Disposing session as kernel process died ExitCode: undefined, Reason: objc[15987]: Class CaptureDelegate is implemented in both ~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/cv2/cv2.abi3.so (0x167372520) and ~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/mediapipe/.dylibs/libopencv_videoio.3.4.16.dylib (0x11d1dc860). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[15987]: Class CVWindow is implemented in both ~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/cv2/cv2.abi3.so (0x167372570) and ~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/mediapipe/.dylibs/libopencv_highgui.3.4.16.dylib (0x10a448a68). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[15987]: Class CVView is implemented in both ~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/cv2/cv2.abi3.so (0x167372598) and ~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/mediapipe/.dylibs/libopencv_highgui.3.4.16.dylib (0x10a448a90). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[15987]: Class CVSlider is implemented in both ~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/cv2/cv2.abi3.so (0x1673725c0) and ~/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/mediapipe/.dylibs/libopencv_highgui.3.4.16.dylib (0x10a448ab8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```